# Azure data bricks shared workspace notebooks integration with azure Repos Git?

Tags: git, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-repos, azure-notebooks

My requirement is I have all my notebooks placed in the shared workspace of Azure Databricks, Now I want to integrate azure repos git with my databricks notebooks, and while integrating by default databricks is taking the notebooks which are under the Users workspace (under my user Email)  instead of shared work space location.

Is there a way to integrate shared workspace notebooks instead of Users workspace with Azure repos git ?

kindly help.

Comment: Not really sure if there is a straight forward way - one possible idea would be to create a pipeline - that will use the databricks-cli to copy the notebooks into a specific folder in the workspace...